# Selenium/ToolTip/Dynamically Generated/Verify Tooltip Text

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, tooltip

I'm having trouble validating the text of tooltips whose html code is generated dynamically when you hover over the buttons. Following is the link of the page I'm trying to work on:

http://www.globalsqa.com/demoSite/practice/tooltip/video-player.html

I tried a lot of things already and searched many forums but nothing helped me out to fetch the text of tooltip, that's first thing.
Another is, there's a  with role as log, that keeps adding up the text value of tooltips when you hover over the buttons. I worked on that part when first thing failed. Here is my code and that just gets me the text value of last hovered button, rest empty fields!

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement a1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/span/button[@title='I like this']"));
    WebElement a2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/span/button[@title='I dislike this']"));
    WebElement a3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/button[@title='Add to Watch Later']"));
    WebElement a4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/button[@title='Add to favorites or playlist']"));
    WebElement a5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/button[@title='Share this video']"));
    WebElement a6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/button[@title='Flag as inappropriate']"));

    builder.moveToElement(a1).moveToElement(a2)
    .moveToElement(a3).moveToElement(a4)
    .moveToElement(a5).moveToElement(a6)
    .perform();

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[@role='log']/div"));
    System.out.println(element.size());
    for(WebElement ele : element)
        System.out.println(ele.getText());
```

If anyone thinks that calling moveToElement for each button individually and using Thread.sleep() in between the moves could work, I tried already but did not work!
To be specific, I want tooltip text value of all 6 buttons when you hover over them one-by-one. Selenium version(3.0.1), Browser(Chrome:Version 55.0.2883.87 m)

Addition: This is how div tag builds, attaching html code:

```
<div role="log" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><div style="display: none;">I like this</div><div style="display: none;">I dislike this</div><div style="display: none;">Add to Watch Later</div><div style="display: none;">Add to favorites or playlist</div><div style="display: none;">Share this video</div><div>Flag as inappropriate</div></div>
<div style="display: none;">I like this</div>
<div style="display: none;">I dislike this</div>
<div style="display: none;">Add to Watch Later</div>
<div style="display: none;">Share this video</div>
<div style="display: none;">Add to Watch Later</div>
<div>Flag as inappropriate</div>
```

Comment: when you use the Action (builder) and perform the action, does the tooltip appear?

Comment: Yes, it appears. I used Thread.sleep() to verify that. What still confusing me is why I cannot retrieve values all at once when I hover over all buttons and use /div[@role='log']. I see all text values in html when I inspect page source.

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` only gets the visible text of an element, so unless all your tooltips are still visible when you get their text, only the last one will give you text -- which is what you're seeing.

What you could do to get around this is executing javascript on each element and getting the `textContent` property. Either that or get the text after each move while the popup is still visible

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lucas. I was previously avoiding that iterate element thing but it worked with following code. You can see I'm still not using the tooltip element but the div tag with **role as log** for my values. I will try for javascript as well and put an answer. Here's my code for first two buttons, if someone needs a reference:

```
builder.moveToElement(a1).perform();
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[@role='log']/div"));
        System.out.println(element.get(element.size()-1).getText());

    builder.moveToElement(a2).perform();
    element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[@role='log']/div"));
        System.out.println(element.get(element.size()-1).getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the page's HTML in Chrome console, and as I'm not writing the code  I wanted to make sure the tooltip appeared (as I asked you).
The locator for the tooltip element could be the following XPath (you can check it in the Chrome's console using something like `$x("//your/xpath/here")`:

```
"//div[@role='tooltip']"
```

Have into account that as this element is added dynamically, the selector only works when the tooltip is visible; as soon as you move the pointer, and the tooltip disappears, the element also gets removed from the page, and that locator doesn't work.

So your code should be something like:

```
builder.moveToElement(a1).perform();
String tooltipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='tooltip']")).getText();
```

In this case, better work with `By` instead of  a`WebElement` because the element is being created and destroyed dynamically.

Let me know if it works, hope it helps.

Comment: `"div[role='tooltip']"` as a CSS selector, also works in Chrome console. You can try using `$("your css selector")`